# Static Route Dual LAN CARD Centos 6

Tags: networking, centos, routing, centos6, nic

First let me explain the scenario. I have two internet connection (Lease LINE and BroadBand).

I have a CENTOS 6 Server which is used for VOIP calling (GOAUTODIAL). Now I want everyone in the LAN to use the broadband and the server should use the lease line but then again the server should also be accessible locally.

So, say I feed the broadband to a router and setup it up to have a LAN Network 192.168.0.0/24.

Next I feed the Lease line to the SERVER and set the static LIVE IP on eth0 say 200.200.200.200

Now, I am looking for a solution to put the server on 192.168.0.0/24 Network.

In order to do this the cheapest solution would to have another LAN CARD installed in the server and set a 192.168.0.0/24 IP on it. Say 192.168.0.254

Now, all the outgoing calls through the server is connected to a static IP say 116.116.116.116

Now, I want all the outgoing or incoming request from 116.116.116.116 to be handled by eth1 (200.200.200.200 - Lease LINE). Apart from this every thing else should be handled by the eth0(192.168.0.254).

For Example I have NFS server running on the server machine. It should be accessible from the 192.168.0.0/24 Network.

I am sorry if this was too long, please guide me through this hurdle.

I know I have to play around with route-eth0 and route-eth1. But I am not sure how to go about it.A bit of guidance or a link to a tutorial would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If the server has 2 NICs and eth0 is the 'pubic' one and eth1 the 'local' one, then you don't need to do anything special.

You simply configure eth0 with your public IP and a default gateway and eth1 with 192.168.0.254 IP (or whichever else you want from your local subnet) and every device on that *same* LAN will be able to reach your server without any special static routes.

I didn't fully understand the part about the incoming requests from `116.116.116.116` though.

Is this server some kind of SIP Server/Proxy?

Comment: Yes, it is a SIP server.